TeXLive 2024 error when building R-4.3.3
TeXLive2024 downloaded from the 'Net is installed on my Slackware64-15.0 laptop. When building R-4.3.3 it fails toward the end when trying to build a vignette:
* DONE (mgcv)
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/SBo/R-4.3.3/src/library/Recommended'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/SBo/R-4.3.3/src/library/Recommended'
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/SBo/R-4.3.3/src/library'
building/updating vignettes for package 'grid' ...
building/updating vignettes for package 'parallel' ...
building/updating vignettes for package 'utils' ...
building/updating vignettes for package 'stats' ...
processing 'reshape.Rnw'
Error: compiling TeX file 'reshape.tex' failed with message:
Running 'texi2dvi' on 'reshape.tex' failed.
Messages:
/usr/bin/texi2dvi: TeX neither supports -recorder nor outputs \openout lines in its log file
Execution halted
make[1]: *** [Makefile:103: vignettes] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/SBo/R-4.3.3/src/library'
make: *** [Makefile:81: vignettes] Error 2

I've not before had issues building R versions using TeXLive and need advice on how to resolve this issue.
TIA,
Rich

are you using tl2024 at all, the log just shows texi2dvi being called (which isn't a texlive program)

texi2dvi is a program with the Linux package ``texinfo`or so. The help of the homologous function of R tools explain: A shell script texi2dvi is part of GNU's texinfo. Several issues have been seen with released versions, so if yours does not work correctly try R_TEXI2DVICMD=emulation.  Occasionally indices contain special characters which cause indexing to fail (particularly when using the ‘⁠hyperref⁠’ LaTeX package) even on valid input. The argument index = FALSE is provided to allow package manuals to be made when this happens: it uses emulation.
